# KDB/Q: how to loop without loops?

Tags: kdb

I am learning q on kdb database. I am concerned by the fact that there are no loops in q.
I need to write an algorithm that I would write with several nested for-loops in a verbose program like C. But in q I am stuck by the fact that I cannot loop.

Just to give a specific example (one of many), I have this simple vector (column table):

```
q)closures
price
-----
18.54
18.53
18.53
18.52
18.57
18.9 
18.9 
18.77
18.59
18.51
18.37
```

I need a vector that groups 3by3 these entries, with superposition, like (using R syntax):
closures[0:2],closures[1:3],closures[2:4],closures[3:5]...
How can I do?

In general, how do I need to change my mentality, to correctly program in q?

Thanks a lot for your suggestions
Marco

Comment: It's not true that q has no loops, it's just that you are discouraged from using them unless you really have to. There are some cases where using a loop is absolutely the right thing to do, and for that you would want to check out the `while` and `do` keywords.

Answer (score 10):

Addressing your last point about "how do I need to change my mentality, to correctly program in q?":

You need to utilise over (/), scan (\) and .z.s rather than using loops.

For example, your problem could be solved in the following ways: 
(note that these would not actually be the best solutions for your particular problem - indexing is the better approach there - but nonetheless these solutions below should help get the point across)

```
price:18.54 18.53 18.53 18.52 18.57 18.9 18.9 18.77 18.59 18.51 18.37

q)3#'{1_x}\[8;price]
18.54 18.53 18.53
18.53 18.53 18.52
18.53 18.52 18.57
18.52 18.57 18.9
18.57 18.9  18.9
18.9  18.9  18.77
18.9  18.77 18.59
18.77 18.59 18.51
18.59 18.51 18.37
```

i.e iterate over the list, chop one off each time, take first 3 of each iteration

or similarly

```
q)3#'{1 rotate x}\[8;price]
18.54 18.53 18.53
18.53 18.53 18.52
18.53 18.52 18.57
18.52 18.57 18.9
18.57 18.9  18.9
18.9  18.9  18.77
18.9  18.77 18.59
18.77 18.59 18.51
18.59 18.51 18.37
```

i.e. rotate by 1 eight times, take first 3 of each rotation

Using a .z.s approach

```
q){$[2<count x;enlist[3#x],.z.s 1_x;()]}[price]
18.54 18.53 18.53
18.53 18.53 18.52
18.53 18.52 18.57
18.52 18.57 18.9
18.57 18.9  18.9
18.9  18.9  18.77
18.9  18.77 18.59
18.77 18.59 18.51
18.59 18.51 18.37
```

i.e. if there are at least 3 elements left, take first 3, then chop off first item and re-apply same function to the shortened list.

Using over (/) would be convoluted in this example but in general over is usful for replacing "while" type constructs

```
i:0
a:0;
while[i<10;i+:1;a+:10]
```

is better achieved using

```
q){x+10}/[10;0]
100
```

i.e. add 10, ten times with a starting (seed) value of zero.

```
b:();  
while[not 18~last b;b,:1?20]
```

i.e keep appending random numbers between 1 and 20 until you hit 18, then stop.

is better achieved using

```
q){x,1?20}/[{not 18~last x};()]
1 2 16 5 8 18
```

i.e append a random number between 1 and 20, iterate so long as the check function returns true, starting off with () as seed value

There are many other options for using scan and over, depending on whether the function you're iterating over is monadic/diadic etc.

As a broad generalisation:
a "for i=1:10" type loop can be achieved in q using "function each i",
a "do" type loop can be achieved in q using "function/[numOfTimes;seed]",
a "while" type loop can be achieved in q using "function/[booleanCheckFunction;seed]"

Answer (score 3):

```
flip (-2_price;-1_1_price;2_price)
```

As already mentioned using builtins is always faster than iteration with ' or /. That's why on a vecor of 1 million elements the code from the top answer takes forever to complete and uses GBs of heap. The indexing method from JPC and Harshal is miles faster but the flip above is three times faster still.

Once you have the data in the format you need just use [each](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/control/#each) to apply your closure to the elements of the list.

Always keeping an eye on what \t tells you is a good practice - KDB will not optimize anything for you.

Answer (score 2):

As for nested loops something i have found useful is creating a cross list.
E.g

`for i=1:10

```
 for j=1:20
    for k=1:30
      f(i, j, k)
```

`

in q you can

```
il: 1 _til 11
jl: 1_til 21
kl: 1_til 31
lst: il cross jl cross kl
raze g(x) each til count ls
```

where g is defined as

```
g: {[i]
itr: first lst[i];
jtr: first 1_lst[i];
ktr: last lst[i];

f(itr, jtr, ktr)
}
```

Hope this clarifies. As for the closures part don't know R syntax there. Can help if you can tell what output you want.

Comment: In R the notation, e.g. [1:3] means the vector (1,2,3).
So I meant that I wanted this output (taking the vector "closures" as above):
18.54 18.53 18.53 18.52 18.57 18.9 18.9 18.77 18.59 18.51 18.37

Comment: In R the notation, e.g. [1:3] means the vector (1,2,3).
So I meant that I wanted this output (taking the vector "closures" as above):
(18.54 18.53 18.53 )
(18.53 18.53 18.52)
(18.53 18.52 18.57 )
.......
i.e.
(closures[0] closures[1] closures[2] )
(closures[1] closures[2] closures[3] )(closures[2] closures[3] closures[4] )
......

Anyway I solved temporarily the problem using a q while loop. But it looks so innatural in q.
I just think I am on the wrong way with mental approach

Comment: this should solve the problem for you. `{[x;y] 3#y _ x} [(1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9)] each til 7`

Answer (score 2):

One method would be to calculate the indices you care about and then index into the array -

```
q) f:{y til[x]+/:neg[x]_til count y} // [x] = sublist length [y] = list
q) f[3;18.54 18.53 18.53 18.52 18.57 18.9 18.9 18.77 18.59 18.51 18.37]
    18.54 18.53 18.53
    18.53 18.53 18.52
    18.53 18.52 18.57
    18.52 18.57 18.9
    18.57 18.9  18.9
    18.9  18.9  18.77
    18.9  18.77 18.59
    18.77 18.59 18.51
```

Comment: Cool. I had {x flip til[y]+\:til count[x]-y-1}

Answer (score 2):

KDB Q being a vector processing language, it's strength lies in processing *lists* as opposed to processing individual *atoms* as regularly done in imperative languages.

However, in case you are not aware, Q does have support for loops and can be used in cases where these seems no other way! Here's an example I had written while I had started migrating from Java to KDB Q

```
isPrime:{[num] i:2; flag:1b; while[i<=sqrt num; if[(num mod i)~0;flag:0b];i:i+1]; flag}
```

It also has `do-while` kinda syntax

```
    i : 0;
    do [5;
        // Iterated action involving i
        0N!i; //printing i
        i : i + 1
    ];
```

Have a look [here](http://www.thalesians.com/finance/index.php/Knowledge_Base/Databases/Kdb#Loops_with_indices)

Answer (score 2):

Q does have traditional looping constructs: [do](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/control/#do) to repeat a statement given number of times and [while](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/control/#while) to repeat while a given condition holds.  In addition, q "adverbs" [each](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/control/#each), [over](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/control/#over), etc.  let you "loop" a function over elements of a vector.

However, to take the full advantage of the power of q you should learn how to avoid explicit loops.

Simplifying your specific example (to use a simple vector rather than a 1-column table), here is how you can regroup a vector of prices:

```
q)price:18.54 18.53 18.53 18.52 18.57 18.9 18.9 18.77 18.59 18.51 18.37
q)2_flip(prev x;x:prev x;x:price)
18.54 18.53 18.53
18.53 18.53 18.52
18.53 18.52 18.57
18.52 18.57 18.9
18.57 18.9  18.9
18.9  18.9  18.77
18.9  18.77 18.59
18.77 18.59 18.51
18.59 18.51 18.37
```

Here is how it works.  (Remember: q evaluates from right to left.)  The [prev](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/select/#prev) function shifts the prices to the right in the vector (prepending null values at the start and discarding the last value:

```
q)prev price
0n 18.54 18.53 18.53 18.52 18.57 18.9 18.9 18.77 18.59 18.51
q)prev prev price
0n 0n 18.54 18.53 18.53 18.52 18.57 18.9 18.9 18.77 18.59
```

We combine the original price vector with two shifted in a $3 \times n$ matrix.  The columns of this matrix are the groups that we want.  The [flip](http://code.kx.com/q/ref/lists/#flip) function transposes the matrix so that you get the groups as rows and finally we drop the first two rows that contain null values using the `_` operator.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @wai-ha-lee: This answers the specific question of how to group prices without a loop.  What did I miss?

Comment: Your answer is stated without explanation and could be classified as code-only, which means that its usefulness is limited to addressing the specific problem at hand. With comments/explanation, an answer is a lot more useful to the wider community.

Answer (score 0):

Like some of the above users have suggested, I think the best think to do here is calculat the indices you want. When possible, avoid lambdas and use operators (it is better style).

```
 q)v:18.54 18.53 18.53 18.52 18.57 18.9 18.9 18.77 18.59 18.51 18.37
 q)v (0 1 2)+/:til count v ///generate a list of indices from 0 to the count of v, then add 0 1 2 to each of those indices
18.54 18.53 18.53
18.53 18.53 18.52
18.53 18.52 18.57
18.52 18.57 18.9
18.57 18.9  18.9
18.9  18.9  18.77
18.9  18.77 18.59
18.77 18.59 18.51
18.59 18.51 18.37
18.51 18.37
18.37
```